# Scanned value(using scanner) in the textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-applications, barcode-scanner

I am using `Scanner` (basic model) to scan the barcode. Scanned barcode will be captured in a textbox. In `txtBarcode_TextChanged` event, I am getting the barcode to access.

Problem:

If I click the scanner more than once, the barcode gets append with the previous value.

**My Code:**

```
protected void txtBarcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txt = this.txtBarcode.Text;
    this.txtBarcode.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, perhaps the english isn't perfect, but what he wants is clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing with barcode scanners is that they usually present themselves looking like a standard HID keyboard.  Therefore, each new code scanned is effectively 'typed' after the previous one.  A solution I have used in the past is to see how much time passes between key presses in that textbox.  If it's more than 10 milliseconds (or around that value, I believe this was the largest amount of time taken for the scanner I was using to 'type' an entire code), then it's a new barcode, and you should delete everything before it.

I haven't got an IDE to hand, so most of the class/method names are probably way off, but something like an example:

```
DateTime lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;

void txtBarcode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{

   if(((TimeSpan) (DateTime.Now - lastKeyPress)).TotalMilliseconds > 10)
   {
     txtBarcode.Text = "";      
   }
   lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I think that should do it.  It works because the KeyPress event occurs before the character is appended, so you can clear the textbox first.

**Edit**: To set up, I guess that wherever you have `txtBarcode.TextChanged += txtBarcode_TextChanged`, you instead have a `txtBarcode.KeyPress += txtBarcode_KeyPress`. Check the event name is right though.

**Edit 2**:

---

jQuery Version:

Assuming this HTML (since you are using ASP, your source for the input tag will look different, but the output will still have the `id` attribute, which is really the only one that matters):

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="txtBarcode" id="txtBarcode" />
    </form>
```

Then this javascript works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

   $("#txtBarcode").keypress(function(event)
   {
        var currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

        if(currentTimestamp - timestamp > 50)
        {
            $(this).val("");
        }
        timestamp = currentTimestamp;
   });                                

});
```

It seems that (at least in a web browser) 50 milliseconds is the required time to allow between characters.  I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE7.

Comment: I've added it to the answer, see the Edit.

Comment: Actually, does this need to be jquery handling an event on a text input on a web page? Different code entirely if so.

Answer (score 2):

try to change TextChanged event handler to kind of this:

```
txtBarcode.SelectionStart = 0;  
txtBarcode.SelectionLength = txtBarcode.Text.Length;
```

It will select text in textbox after reading the code and rewrite it on other read. + it will be more suitable for users to copy it or change by hand

Comment: Are you using .NET TextBox class? If so, there must be SelectionStart, SelectionLength. I used this code myself when was working with barcodereader and wanted to rewrite previously read barcode.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtBarcode" runat="server" CssClass="hidden_field"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: oops..i thought you have winforms(missed the tags about javascript). Then maybe this will help and do the same i did in winforms: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/288734-selecting-all-text-textbox

Answer (score 2):

Most scanners can be programmed to "press enter" after scanning, check your user manual. You can use a Keypress or Keydown event handler to check for the "enter" key and use it as delimiter for your barcode. You can also use a special delimiting character if you prefer.

```
 private void txtScan_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
               //Do something here...

                txtScan.Text = "";
                txtScan.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                e.Handled = true;  //keeps event from bubbling to next handler
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var _lastRead = new Date();

    function Validate(control) {
      var _now = new Date();
      if ((_now - _lastRead) > 10) {
        control.value = "";
      }
      _lastRead = new Date();
    }
  </script>
  <input type="text" id="txtInput" onkeypress="Validate(this);" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're assigning `txtBarcode.value += barcode`, change it to `txtBarcode.value = barcode`

Comment: -1: He uses a barcode scanner. He is not appending the text in his code.